# Why use command M-x jedi:install-server in Emacs doesn't reply

Tags: emacs, jedi

I am trying to install Jedi for emacs26 using MELPA package by following instructions here --http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/released/.I used `pip3` to install 'jedi flake8 autopep8' and I also use `M-x package-list`to intstall `jedi`.But When I use `M-x jedi:install-server` ,It only shows:
`Running: pip install --upgrade /home/lzzz/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-core-20181207.1/...`
[Runing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SE2Qy.png)

After a long time, it didn't reply anything.I don't know what should I do.Is my configure's or network's wrong? I need help.

[the jedi error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdGiv.png)

## `Error (jedi):

## Failed to start Jedi EPC server.

*** EPC Error ***
Server may raise an error. Use "M-x epc:pop-to-last-server-process-buffer RET" to see full traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lzzz/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-core-20181207.1/jediepcserver.py", line 39, in 
    import jedi
ImportError: No module named jedi

*** EPC Server Output (last 10 lines) ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lzzz/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-core-20181207.1/jediepcserver.py", line 39, in 
    import jedi
ImportError: No module named jedi

*** EPC Server Config ***
Server arguments: ("python" "/home/lzzz/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-core-20181207.1/jediepcserver.py")
Actual command: /usr/bin/python
VIRTUAL_ENV envvar: nil

*** jedi-mode is disabled in # ***
Fix the problem and re-enable it.

*** You may need to run "M-x jedi:install-server". ***
This could solve the problem especially if you haven't run the command yet
since Jedi.el installation or update and if the server complains about
Python module imports.
`

Comment: Is the environment you ran `pip3` the same that emacs is calling with `M-x jedi:install-server`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that Jedi is not starting the server with the same Python environment as the one in which you installed the dependencies.

I would suggest that you first find out which Python executable corresponds to the `pip3` you used to install dependencies. Let's say it is `/usr/local/bin/python3`. Then add the following to your `.emacs`:

```lisp
(setq 'jedi:server-command 
      '("/usr/local/bin/python3" "/home/lzzz/.emacs.d/elpa/jedi-core-20181207.1/jediepcserver.py"))
```

Then, try to run `M-x jedi:ac-setup` in a python buffer (you shouldn't need the `M-x installe-server` since you went for the manual installation).

Hope this helps!